# Return most recent value of multiple time series in Prometheus/PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a query with a gauge metric that returns two time series, one for each `instance` label.

Query:
`my_metric{type="user"}[5m]`

Result:

```
my_metric{instance="a", type="user"}
75 @1692368662.678
90 @1692368692.678
100 @1692368722.678

my_metric{instance="b", type="user"}
60 @1692368661.935
100 @1692368667.663
110 @1692368691.935
```

I want the query to return the most recent value. So, for example, if 60 (from instance `b`) is the most recent one, that's what I want to return, ignoring the other instances.

I tried to use `last_over_time` as in `last_over_time(my_metric{type="user"}[5m])` but this still returns both time series.

Comment: How often does your values changes? Is it happening more often then once every 5 minutes?

Comment: You can probably start with `my_metric{type="user"} and timestamp(my_metric{type="user"}) == on() group_left() max(timestamp(my_metric{type="user"}))`. It is not ideal near value change, but good starting point in searches.

Comment: The value changes once every 5 minutes. So for one instance it may change at least once every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `max`, `timestamp` and logical operators for this:

```
my_metric{type="user"} and timestamp(my_metric{type="user"}) == on() group_left() max(timestamp(my_metric{type="user"}))
```

Here we return value of metric if it's timestamp is the maximum timestamp among all timestamps of these metrics.

Demo of similar query [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up%20and%20timestamp(up%7B%7D)%20%3D%3D%20on()%20group_left()%20max(timestamp(up%7B%7D))&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1m).

If you want to get only value without different labels you can wrap everything into `sum(  )`.